# Where is the locking file for an open msaccess database

Tags: ms-access

I have always relied on the absence of the .ldb file to install a new .mdb database over the existing one. Now I have converted the application to .accdb, a locking file is no longer created.

Is there an other way to see whether the application is currently running or not, or a setting in msaccess to always generate a locking database?

Comment: are you sure it is not creating any locking file? for accdb file it generate a locking  file with name as  your databasename.laccdb .

Comment: It does create a backend.laccdb when a table is open but the frontend.laccdb is missing. It seems that msaccess .accdb applications only create a locking db when tables are accessed. This behaviour differs from .mdb applications.

I need way to see whether the front end can be overwritten.

Comment: in my case it always generate the locking file both in frontend and backend

Comment: Are you opening the front-end with the /excl command line parameter?  If you open an mdb or accdb exclusively, with /excl, Access will not create a lock file.  However, your backend linked tables will still create a lock file since they are opened differently.

Comment: I generally don't let my users use my _original_ front end.  They have to copy it to their own location first.  Combine this with some kind of version control and you generally don't have to worry about your front end being open and the users are informed when there's a new version available.

Comment: Yes, it is called with the /excl parameter. Both front end and back end are installed locally.

Comment: If you are using a script to update the front-end then you should be able to just try the copy and catch the error if it fails.